# How can I deselect radio buttons when back button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a webpage where the user can select through a number of radio groups. If the user clicks on a link and leaves the page then hits the back button to return to the page the browsers default behavior is to remember the users previous selections and to keep them.

Is it possible to use JavaScript(jQuery ok) to deselect previous selections in the case of the back button being used? In console I can deselect by using either .reset() or .checked = false; But my issue is getting this to run when the back button is pressed.

Here is a basic example where I've tried to run code on the popstate event. If you select an option and click the link, then right click in the window and select 'back', the radio you checked will be still be selected.

```js
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
 document.getElementById("radio-group").reset();
}, false);
```

```html
<!-- SCREEN ONE -->
<div>
  <form id="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="letter" value="A" id="radio-1"><label for="radio-1"><span>A</span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="letter" value="B" id="radio-2"><label for="radio-2"><span>B</span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="letter" value="C" id="radio-3"><label for="radio-3"><span>C</span></label>
  </form>
</div>

<a href="something">link</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event) event is working fine:

```js
window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
 document.getElementById("radio-group").reset();
}, false);
```

```html
<!-- SCREEN ONE -->
<div>
  <form id="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="letter" value="A" id="radio-1"><label for="radio-1"><span>A</span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="letter" value="B" id="radio-2"><label for="radio-2"><span>B</span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="letter" value="C" id="radio-3"><label for="radio-3"><span>C</span></label>
  </form>
</div>

<a href="something">link</a>
```

Also you can use `beforeunload` event

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`pageshow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageshow_event) event:

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
        document.getElementById("radio-group").reset();
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems to me this is currently only supported in Firefox.